# rtorrent error shared libraries

Tags: shared-library, rtorrent

I believe an apt update changed something and now rtorrent is failing to load.

```
rtorrent: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

This is on Ubuntu 16.04.

Running `sudo find / -name "libcrypto.so.*"` shows to locations of different versions of the so.

- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0

Comment: Did you try to install it with `sudo apt install libcrypto++9v5`? What's the output of this?

Comment: @dessert That package wasn't installed but It's still complaining :(

Comment: If this doesn't help, try `sudo apt install -f`, and if that also doesn't help, `sudo apt --reinstall install rtorrent`.

Comment: And you may `sudo apt purge libcrypto++9v5` if it's not needed. ;)

Comment: Installing rtorrent from apt fixed it. I was running a build from source version before which I guess is why when the dependencies changed it all broke. :/

Comment: It would be good to include such information in the question next time. ;) You may have two versions of `rtorrent` on your system now, I recommend to remove both of them and make a clean install of `rtorrent` from the package sources.

Comment: If it solved your question, please accept my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt --reinstall install rtorrent
```

fixed it in this case. OP was runnig a version manually built from source before, but when `libcrypto.so.1.0.2` was not available on the system any more due to an update it refused to work. Installing `rtorrent` from the package sources solves the problem in such a case. For 16.04 this has no downsides as package sources hold version 0.9.6, which is the most recent one at the moment. However, if there is a non-package-system version installed it's a good idea to remove this first before installing the package version, to avoid collisions and keep the system clean.

Comment: Software not managed by apt cannot be removed by apt.